# Collection View not showing cell

Tags: swift, xcode, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I've been trying to create a collection view for days.
I have already created several Collection Views. That worked without any problems. Only this time I can't find the error.

The problem:
I have an array of Image URLs.
These should be displayed in an image view.
The Collection View cell is not displayed.
The queries `print(CollectionView.visibleCells)` always returns 0.
However, the array contains elements.

Here is my code.

```
import UIKit

class FreierAuftragAnlegenVC: UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var cvFotos: UICollectionView!
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        
        return aktuellerFreierAuftrag.fotoURLs.count
        
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = cvFotos.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! freierAuftragAnlegenCVC
        
       let url = URL(string: aktuellerFreierAuftrag.fotoURLs[indexPath.row])
        
        if let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url!) {
            if UIImage(data: data) != nil {
                cell.ivFoto.image = UIImage(data: data)
            } else {
                print("kein Foto hinter der URL")
            }
        }
        return cell
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
         return CGSize (width: 100, height: 200)
     }

    @IBAction func btTEst(_ sender: Any) {
        cvFotos.reloadData()
        print(aktuellerFreierAuftrag.fotoURLs.count)
        print(cvFotos.visibleCells)
    }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        cvFotos.dataSource = self
        cvFotos.delegate = self
        cvFotos.collectionViewLayout = UICollectionViewLayout()
}
    
}
```

```
import UIKit

class freierAuftragAnlegenCVC: UICollectionViewCell {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var ivFoto: UIImageView!
    
}
```

[image]

[image]

Where could the problem be?

Comment: Where is `aktuellerFreierAuftrag.photoURLs` populated? And why are the photoURLs not declared as `[URL]`.   Any calculation/conversion inside `cellForItem` is unnecessarily expensive.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt reply. "aktuellerFreierAuftrag.photoURLs" is published in another part of the project. I created an array of strings because this file should be uploaded to the Google firebase. This only accepts String. I've also tried using an array of strings to create labels from them. Unfortunately without success. For some reason the cell is not created.

Comment: What is the count of `aktuellerFreierAuftrag.fotoURLs.count` ? Is `cellForItemAt indexPath` being called if you place a breakpoint ?

Comment: I now added two urls permanently to the array. So the count of `aktuellerFreierAuftrag.fotoURLs.count` is 2. I'm not sure if I did the right thing with the breaking point. I set the breaking point to `func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell`. The program just kept going.

Comment: @Andreas - it should be somewhere inside the body of the function ideally rather than on the line where you define the function name and params. However if it just kept going without stopping means something is not set up right. Probably you have not set your view controller as the `datasource` of your collection view in your storyboard ?

Comment: I already had the assumption with `dataSource`. However, I have already set this in the storyboard. Do you have any idea where the error could be?

Comment: @Andreas I have many ideas, but cannot be sure what the exact issue is with the info above. Another could be, the delegate is not set properly so a call to `sizeForItemAt indexPath` will not be made and your cells won't have a size. If you can put this isolated runnable code on some repo, I could take a look if you wish. Please tag me though using `@` otherwise I don't get the notifications.

Comment: @Shawn Frank I found the problem. It was `cvFotos.collectionViewLayout = UICollectionViewLayout()`in `viewDidLoad`. I think that only worked in my other projects because I first loaded the data from Firebase and there was a time delay. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Happy to hear that @Andreas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dear you are inheriting from `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout` only. Please add `UICollectionViewDataSource`, `UICollectionViewDelegate` as well

I think you are using `UIPickerViewDataSource`, `UIPickerViewDelegate` by mistake.

Comment: sorry, i copied that wrong.
I used UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource. That wasn't the problem

Comment: than what is the count of aktuellerFreierAuftrag.fotoURLs???

Comment: and please upVote at least this point..

Comment: the count of aktuellerFreierAuftrag.fotoURLs is 1